# Data retrieving from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to get the data from a table in Java. I have been able to get the data but when it is being output, it is concatenated by itself.  If the data is "admin" the output is "adminadmin". Below is the code. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
package sample;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class Table extends JFrame{
    JTable table;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    private int row;
    private String name, status;

    private void connect(){
        conn = myconnection.ConnectDb();
    }


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int sel = table.getSelectedRow();
        name = table.getModel().getValueAt(sel, 0).toString();
        System.out.print(name);
    }
});
    }

    private void UpdateJTable(){

        String sql = "select firstname, status from tblmember";

        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }


    public Table(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        String [] columnName={"Name", "Status"};
        Object [][] data={
            {null, null},
            {null, null}
        };

        table = new JTable(data, columnName);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400,50));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(sp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Table gui = new Table();

        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(700, 500);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("AAAAAAAA");
        gui.connect();
        gui.UpdateJTable();
        gui.mouseClicked(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: *"Can someone tell me what the problem is?"*  Now that (along with the failing code) is what I call a ***specific*** question.  +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

It's concatenated because the selection event is triggered twice, and you use `System.out.print()` to display the selection.

You should probably ignore the event if its `getValueIsAdjusting()` method returns true.

Also, be careful that the selected row index returned is not necessarily the same index as the table model index: if your table is sorted, both indexes will differ. Use JTable's `convertRowIndexToModel()` before getting the data from the model.

Comment: ...can you tell me how to do it please...you told that the selection event is triggered twice, so how to correct it.

Comment: As I said: by ignoring the event if its getValueIsAdjusting() method returns true.

Comment: @ JB Nizet...i am unable to do it mate:( can you give me the sample coding please...i would be very grateful to you.

Comment: What have you tried? You know how to call a method, and how to use `if`, don't you? What's hard in `if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {...}`? This is really basic Java. Don't use Swing if you don't know how to do such a simple thing. Learn the basics first.

Comment: correct answer, of course - though not the whole problem: the number of notifications will increase with the number of clicks :-) @Ravi77 there is _absolutely_ no way around reading and understanding some basic tutorial (as you have been advised in your previous question)

Comment: @kleopatra: in fact, the mouseClicked method is not invoked from any listener. Only from the main method, with null as argument. It's stupid to name trhis method like this and make it take an argument, but it won't cause the problem you described.

Comment: arrgggghhh ... was wrong with the mouseClicked remark .. crazy code is _not_ the implementation of a MouseListener but a single method with same signature as one of its methods and called once ...

Comment: you beat me by a whole minute :-)